# How to test model method with new rspec syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In the below spec, I want to test that for a `Notification` instance, running the destructive method `#mark_as_dismissed` will change the `has_been_read` column to true. How do you do that while keeping the test nice and terse?

```
context "#mark_as_dismissed" do
  subject { create(:notification) }
  subject.mark_as_dismissed # How do I specify this
  its(:has_been_read) { should be_true }
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's multiple ways to write tests and different preferred syntaxes, so this is quite an opinionated answer.

Following your style, it would look more like this:

```
describe "#mark_as_dismissed" do
  subject { create(:notification) }
  before { subject.mark_as_dissmissed }

  its(:has_been_read) { should be_true }
end
```

Mine would be more like this:

```
describe "#mark_as_dismissed" do
  let(:notification) { create(:notification) }

  it "marks the notification as read" do
    notification.mark_as_dissmissed
    notification.has_been_read.should be_true
  end
end
```

**syntatic sugar**: Rspec allows a special syntax for methods returning booleans. I would have to test it, I am not sure it would work in this case but perhaps you can do something like:

```
# for the first alternative
it { should have_been_read }

# for the second alternative
it "marks the notification as read" do
  notification.mark_as_dissmissed
  notification.should have_been_read
end
```

**Bonus points**
To remove the db dependency you can just 'build' the notification instead of using 'create' (which persists the model in the database). If the #mark_as_dismissed method does not need the db (can do a non persistent update), then the test should still work.

build(:notification) # instead of create(:notification)

Comment: Thanks. Bonus points for showing how to remove DB dependency for this spec.